# the event deviceready isn't triggered on my apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, vue.js

I'm trying to load a cordova plugin using vue.js, and vue-cordova.

I'm using vue-cordova, with the plugin open-native-settings to access to the settings of the device (ios or android).
This works just fine with the demo app provided by the vue-cordova plugin on github, but when i add it to my apps (the same way) the event seems to never trigger.
So i tried to wait for the event using

`Vue.cordova.on('deviceready', () => {
  // here check for your variable
})`

or with

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
```

but since the event never trigger they are doing nothing.
I'm kinda lost on the way to  get this event to be triggered, so i can load my plugin properly.
I'm a beginner using this so i might be missing something.

**UPDATE**

I'm loading vue-cordova in my main.js this way:

```
import VueCordova from 'vue-cordova'
Vue.use(VueCordova, {
optionTestKey: 'optionTestValue'
})
```

after that, i try to load the plugins in another view this way:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
//some code here
mounted: function() {
this.cloudyConnection();
this.lastUpdateDate = this.getLastUpdateDate();
if (this.cordova.deviceready === true) {
  this.onDeviceReady()
}
```

},
I also tried to do it out of the mounted function and with the function listed above.

I also added the `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in www/index.html as indicated by a--m but this doesn't do anything

I thank you all for the time you take to help me !

Comment: It's hard to tell without see the actual code... Maybe you are adding the listener after the application triggers the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from http://kartsims.github.io/vue-cordova/ troubleshooting section:

> “My events don’t seem to be fired”
>
> Cordova documentation isn’t obvious about it but you need to include the following script tag in your www/index.html.
>
> `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

Ensure that `cordova.js` is loaded before your scripts and `vue-cordova` since the last depends on that.